# How do I merge two (or more) lists of jQuery objects into one to apply an action to all those objects?

Tags: jquery

I want to have two variables to access two separate objects differently depending on various parameters. For example:

```
this.my_div_ = jQuery(".this-div")
this.my_link_ = jQuery(".this-link")

// in some circumstances:
this.my_div_.hide()
this.my_link_.show()

// in other circumstances:
this.my_div_.show()
this.my_link_.show()

// yet other circumstances:
this.my_div_.show()
this.my_link_.hide()
```

So I need to have two separate jQuery objects for that purpose.

Now I'd like to add a `click()` handle to both of those, the exact same click handled. Obviously, I could have a variable as follow:

```
var handler = e => this.clicked(e)
this.my_div_.click(handler)
this.my_link_.click(handler)
```

Now I'm wondering whether there would be some "magic" where I could merge both `this.my_div_` and `this.my_link_` and set the `click()` handler once for both object?

A way to generate a merge without having to `jQuery()` the objects again. So the equivalent to this but using the existing `this.my_div_` and `this.my_link_`:

```
this.merged_ = jQuery(".this-div, .this-link")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use the `add()` function as follow:

```
this.merged_ = this.my_div_.add(this.my_link_)
```

Which means, if you want to add the `click()` to both objects and don't need the `merged_` variable for anything else, you could write it in one line like this:

```
this.my_div_.add(this.my_link_).click(e => this.clicked(e))
```